# Generic method to determine user identity in method called from SignalR and MVC

Tags: signalr, identity

I have a method in which I need to determine the current user identity. This method can be called both from inside a signalr hub and from code inside the MVC application. Is there a way that I can get the user identity without relying on SignalR Context.User and MVC HttpContext.Current.User and without having to pass the user identity ?
Platform is .Net 4 and MVC3

Comment: Do you want to create your own membership/identity in your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal
```

Will return the underlying HttpContext principal (Or windows principal if in the scope of a client app)